# Administration area keeps redirecting to homepage

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with accessing the administrator site... I googled too much and tried every suggestion that is mentioned in those websites.. but none of them working :S..

After going to mysite.com/administrator, it's redirecting me to site.com/homepage (user page) ..

When I go to plugins, I see there "JhackGuard" installed... I tried to rename from php to .bak but still not working...

Any suggestion ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried to disable the plugin through the database?
In table "prefix_extensions"  at column "enabled" just replace 1 to 0.
It works for similar extensions.

Comment: there is "prefix_extensions" in database.. there is only one "hue1y_extensions" and i set to 0 but still not working :/

Answer (score 1):

If you truly disabled the plugin in database but your admin area is still redirecting you, you can try clearing your browser's cache. In some cases Chrome, Explore and Safari are persistent with redirects...

Answer (score 1):

in this table "`prefix_extensions`" under column name "`name`" and search for "`JHackGuard Plugin`" in column "`enabled`" set value for `0`.

this will disable the plugin.

I also go to column "`name`" and search for value "`com_jhackguard`"
in column "`params`"
I change this:

```
{"enabled":"1","log_level":"1","log_garbage_collection":"7","license_key":"free-version","admin_protection":"1","admin_keyword":"admin","disable_uploads":"1","scan_uploads":"1","use_cymru":"1"}
```

to be:

```
{"enabled":"1","log_level":"1","log_garbage_collection":"7","license_key":"free-version","admin_protection":"0","admin_keyword":"","disable_uploads":"1","scan_uploads":"1","use_cymru":"1"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I'm migrating the website to other server. The admin link -  http://website.com/administrator/index.php  redirect to http://website.com due to some plugin issues, but I was not sure which plugin creating this bug. So I did like below

1. Download the same version of Joomla from here - https://downloads.joomla.org
2. Unzip/Extract it in a new directory - "freshjoomla"
3. In your http://website.com public_html directory, rename the below existing directory (in my case home directory is - /var/www/sites/website.com/public_html/ )

   mv /var/www/sites/website.com/public_html/components /var/www/sites/website.com/public_html/components_old

   mv /var/www/sites/website.com/public_html/plugins /var/www/sites/website.com/public_html/plugins_old

Now copy the fresh components and plugins from freshjoomla directory

```
cp -vr freshjoomla/components /var/www/sites/website.com/public_html/
cp -vr freshjoomla/plugins /var/www/sites/website.com/public_html/
```

Now change the ownership of components, plugins directories to your webserver service username

Most of the cases - www-data for nginx, apache for apache 2

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/sites/website.com/public_html/components
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/sites/website.com/public_html/plugins
```

Now load the admin page - http://website.com/administrator/index.php

Again, download and install the required plugins one by one.

Comment: Looks like a heavy-handed solution, but you have offered a clear and comprehensive explanation.  Thank you for sharing your knowedge with this community.  Welcome to JSX.  Please have a look around and see if you can solve any more issues with high certainty.